# How many times people Share the same items C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, group-by

I have a group of friends who have 0 , 1 or many tokens associated with them.
I am trying to find out out how many times friends share the same token. so if friend1 has tokens 1, 2 and 3 , friend2 has tokens 1 and 2 and friend 3 has tokens 1,2 and 3. It would return that friend 2 and friend1 share 2 tokens while friend3
and friend1 share 3 tokens etc.
I have code that groups the tokens and gets the quantity of friends associated with them. I am just not sure how to get shared tokens with friends. I am thinking there is probably some way to do this with linq, but not sure how or if there is another better way.

```
var summaryOfFriendsAndTokens = distinctFriendList.Where(x => x.oToken != null) // Check for null in the model
    .SelectMany(x => x.oToken) // Flatten
    .GroupBy(x => x.TokenId) // Group

    .Select(group => new // Project
        {
            ItemName = group.Key,
            TotalQuantity = group.Count()
        })
        .ToList();
        ;
    }
}

public class Token {
    public int TokenId { get; set; }
}

public class Friend {
    public List<Token> otoken = new List<Token>();
    private int friendId = -1;
    public int FriendID {
        get { return friendId; }
        set { friendId = value; }
    }

    public List<Token> oToken {
        get { return otoken; }
        set { otoken = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be something like `List<Token> sharedTokens = friend1.oToken.Intersect(friend2.oToken).ToList();`?

Answer (score 0):

For just comparing two friends, we can do something simple, like: `friend1.Tokens.Intersect(friend2.Tokens)`.

With a list of friends, we might want to gather the related data into lists. For each friend in the list, we can get the other friends that share token with him by using the code above in a `Where` clause.

We can also get a list of shared tokens by using `SelectMany` on the `Tokens` property of the group of friends. With these two lists, we can easily display the shared data between each friend and all the others.

Note: I modified the classes to override the `ToString()` method to simplify writing them to the console:

```
public class Token
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"token{Id}";
    }
}

public class Friend
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Token> Tokens { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"friend{Id}";
    }
}
```

Here's one example of displaying the shared token information between a group of friends. The code below creates a list of three friends, the first and third of which have tokens 1, 2, and 3, and the second of which has tokens 1 and 2 (note I called `.ToList()` on the right side of the `Tokens` assignment to ensure that these lists each have a separate location in memory):

```
private static void Main()
{
    var tokens = new List<Token>
    {
        new Token {Id = 1},
        new Token {Id = 2},
        new Token {Id = 3},
    };

    var friends = new List<Friend>
    {
        new Friend {Id = 1, Tokens = tokens.ToList()},
        new Friend {Id = 2, Tokens = tokens.Take(2).ToList()},
        new Friend {Id = 3, Tokens = tokens.ToList()},
    };

    // List out our friends and their shared tokens
    foreach (var friend in friends)
    {
        // Get the friends where the intersection of this friend's tokens 
        // and the other friend's tokens has one or more items
        var sharedFriends = friends.Where(f =>
            f.Id != friend.Id &&
            f.Tokens.Intersect(friend.Tokens).Any());

        if (sharedFriends.Any())
        {
            var sharedTokens = friend.Tokens.Intersect(
                sharedFriends.SelectMany(f => f.Tokens));

            Console.WriteLine($"\n{friend} shares {sharedTokens.Count()} tokens:");

            foreach (var sharedToken in sharedTokens)
            {
                var friendsSharingThisToken =
                    sharedFriends.Where(f => f.Tokens.Contains(sharedToken));

                Console.WriteLine(" - {0} shared with: {1}", sharedToken, 
                    string.Join(", ", friendsSharingThisToken));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\n{friend} is not sharing tokens with anyone else.");
        }
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned...

> or if there is another better way.

Does this help?

```
void Main()
{
    var t1 = new Token {TokenId = 1};
    var t2 = new Token {TokenId = 2};
    var t3 = new Token {TokenId = 3};

    var p1 = new Friend {FriendID = 1, oToken = new List<Token>{t1,t2,t3}};
    var p2 = new Friend {FriendID = 2, oToken = new List<Token>{t1,t2}};
    var p3 = new Friend {FriendID = 3, oToken = new List<Token>{t1,t2,t3}};

    var friends = new List<Friend>{p1,p2,p3};

    for (int i = 0; i < friends.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < friends.Count; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Friend {0} and Friend {1} share {2} tokens", friends[i].FriendID, friends[j].FriendID, friends[i].oToken.Intersect(friends[j].oToken).Count());
        }
    }
}
```

Uses same classes as you have defined.

Comment: I see it works with your code I will have to check my code for other issues.

Comment: To accomplish this with linq, you may need to use complex queries, this approach is easier to understand and more efficient than equivalent linq solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using an extension method that provides the combinations of friends that are possible:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k) {
    return k == 0 ? new[] { new T[0] } :
      elements.SelectMany((e, i) =>
        elements.Skip(i + 1).Combinations(k - 1).Select(c => (new[] { e }).Concat(c)));
}
```

You can count how many tokens are shared by each pair of friends and throw out the pairs that don't share tokens. The LINQ `Intersect` method [produces the set intersection of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Intersect__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) and then we count those common elements.

```
var tokensFriendCount = distinctFriendList.Where(f => f.oToken != null)
                                          .Combinations(2) // get pairs of friends
                                          .Select(fp => fp.ToList()) // convert each sub-IEnumerable to List to make below simpler
                                          .Select(fp => new {
                                              Friend1 = fp[0],
                                              Friend2 = fp[1],
                                              SharedCount = fp[0].oToken.Intersect(fp[1].oToken).Count()
                                          })
                                          .Where(fpc => fpc.SharedCount > 0); // throw out pairs that share no tokens
```

The counting above assumes each `Token` object is unique for a particularly `TokenId` is unique, if that isn't true (though your previous query implies that it is), you can count based on `TokenId`:

```
SharedCount = fp[0].oToken.Select(t => t.TokenId).Intersect(fp[1].oToken.Select(t => t.TokenId)).Count()
```

You can simplify the answer if you just want a summary:

```
var summarySharedTokenCount = tokensFriendCount.Select(tfc => new {
    Friend1Id = tfc.Friend1.FriendID,
    Friend2Id = tfc.Friend2.FriendID,
    tfc.SharedCount
}).ToList();
```

If you don't want to use the extension, these combinations can be generated directly:

```
var tokensFriendCount = distinctFriendList.Where(f => f.oToken != null)
                                          .SelectMany(f => distinctFriendList.Where(f2 => f2.oToken != null && f2.FriendID > f.FriendID).Select(f2 => new[] { f, f2 }))
                                          .Select(fp => new {
                                              Friend1 = fp[0],
                                              Friend2 = fp[1],
                                              SharedCount = fp[0].oToken.Select(t => t.TokenId).Intersect(fp[1].oToken.Select(t => t.TokenId)).Count()
                                          })
                                          .Where(fpc => fpc.SharedCount > 0);
```

Comment: @NetMange  "Combinations" is not Recognized. Do I need to reference anything.

Comment: You need to add the extension method (the first block of code) in a public static class in your project.

Comment: @AmetureBoss I also added an alternative that doesn't use the extension method.

Comment: it  works a brief explanation of how the intersection part works would be nice.

Comment: Added a link to the Microsoft documentation on `Intersect`.